# Moving from hibernate to plain jdbc

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

I have recently started working in Java and J2EE and have theoritical knowledge of concepts related to JDBC and hibernate. I am given a task at my work to convert the existing hibernate connectivity to plain JDBC. Can anybody suggest the simplest way to do it.Actually all tables that i have to work on are created. But I am not able to locate them.Please help.

Comment: I would be interested about the motivation for doing so.

Comment: You don't want to use Hibernate or you don't want to use any ORM? There are other ORM's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all the POJO you already have from Hibernate Mapping and refactor them following some data pattern such as [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html).

Comment: Thank you all.Pierre, The main reason that I want to shift back to Plain JDBC is to get rid of the overheads incurred in using Hibernate.Miller,I don't want to use other ORM's yes.I have gone through some related books and articles and i am able to replace HQLs with SQLs now.

Comment: But, I am not able to do the ones that take session such as:Session s = getSession();try{ List l = super.findAll(s);
            if (!MiscUtils.isEmpty(l)) { HashMap<Integer, Customers> map = new HashMap<Integer, Customers>(l.size());
                Iterator it = MiscUtils.getCollectionIterator(l);
                while (it.hasNext()){
                    Customers c = (Customers) it.next();
                    map.put(c.getId(), c);
                } String q = "select count(*)," + Jobs.PROP_CUSTOMER_ID+ " from Jobs group by " + Jobs.PROP_CUSTOMER_ID;Please suggest some help