# How to design an application to easily swap Hibernate with JDBC

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, orm

First of all, this question may be a duplicate of 
[Moving from hibernate to plain jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855536/moving-from-hibernate-to-plain-jdbc).

But since that question didn't get the answer I'm looking for I'm asking it again.

Let's say we have an application working with Hibernate and we decide to change it all back to JDBC queries. (Hibernate code and dependencies are to be removed completely for some reason)

What is the logical way to do that ? (Step by Step in a chronological order)

Comment: That's highly application dependent.

Comment: Why don't you try JooQ instead of going pure JDBC?

Comment: @fge It's not about optimization or moving to better performance solutions, it's about the logical order of doing such Data layer modifications

Comment: As I said in the comments: I have to "mix" 2 applications, one was developed with JDBC queries and the other one with Hibernate. And since the first one is so much bigger, I want to remove all hibernate dependencies and stick with JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, this is very application dependent but I will try to write some steps that I would take in general:

1) Add the necessary dependencies to your project (if you want to use plain JDBC, you probably have them there already, but if you want to use some additional framework this step may be necessary).

2) Identify all places in your application where you use Hibernate.

3) Replace all these Hibernate queries with JDBC prepared statements. Do this one by one and test that it works. Replacing a query should change the behavior of the application if you write it correctly. You may want to get familiar with your database structure first to avoid mistakes.

4) After rewriting all queries, remove hibernate config files (`*.hbm.xml`) and dependencies from your application.

5) Test once again that everything works correctly.

I am not sure why you want to swap from Hibernate to JDBC though. There are many advantages in using some ORM framework. Have you taken a look on some other frameworks that might suit you better?

[iBatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/) (or myBatis), for example lets you write simplified SQL queries and it is quite easy to learn.

Comment: Thank you! I have to "mix" 2 applications, one was developed with JDBC queries and the other one with Hibernate. And since the first one is so much bigger, it's easier to me to stick with JDBC.

Comment: Ok, I guess it makes sense then. Try it out let me know how it worked :) But consider keeping hibernate in the smaller application and just merging it into the big one. You can still use both Hibernate and JDBC if you configure the Hiernate in the resulting merged app.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It makes no sense.

Long answer: Hibernate is an ORM and so it translates [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) into SQL queries. Things like [cascading](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/), [dirty checking](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/) are handled by Hibernate, so switching to JDBC means you'll have to do it manually.

Switching an ORM with an ActiveRecord approach is an architectural decision that has a significant development cost. Any data access technology is leaky, hence you cannot isolate the data access code so that you can easily swap any technology in and out. Because of performance considerations, you'll have to design your data model and your queries to get the most out of your database.

For a medium-sized enterprise application you need database specific techniques anyway (e.g. CTE, window functions, LATERAL joins), so you need native SQL anyway.

So, the best approach is to use both Hibernate and SQL, instead of picking one or the other.

To give an answer to your question:

You could design the DAO interfaces so that you always return DTOs which means you have two implementations:

- a Hibernate DAO
- JDBC DAO

This way you won't be able to use entities, because the JDBC DAO cannot fetch entity trees nicely, so you need to do it manually anyway.

Using Hibernate for projections only defeats the whole point of using an ORM, so you might question your architecture decision in the first place.

---

Comment: Well, I think I answered the question. A dedicated DAO layer will isolate the application from the data access details. Using DTOs makes the transition possible and you can replace one Hibernate DAO at a time. In the end you can delete the Hibernate DAO and stick with the JDBC ones. So you can run a 100% JDBC data access layer, but then the Hibernate choice was taken poorly when the application architecture was designed.

Comment: Hibernate part of the application is to be removed entirely. I wonder how Cascading and Lazy loading could affect the queries.

Comment: If you are using cascading when persisting/merging entities then you clearly need a way to handle that with JDBC. If you also fetched entity trees and relied on LAZY loading, then you will have to adjust each use case for fetching the exact projection.